# Generate same number by count

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to generate same number  by count with php or javascript for my application. Example my total count is 7

```
<?php
$total = 7;
```

Then I want generate seven 1's like this

```
$split_one = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
```

If my count is 10 then,

```
$split_one = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
```

How to achieve this ..? by php or javascript ..

**Update:**

My output should be like this [1,1,1,1,1,1,1]. Not an array ..

Comment: with javascript: `var arr = [], total = 7; while (arr.length < total) { arr.push(1) }
console.dir(arr);`

Comment: You should check my answer. I've added some extra code to each of the PHP and JS code that would convert this to a string afterwards, per [this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3868571). Also, please use the "add comment" if you want to add a comment, instead of editing the answer.

Comment: Iam sorry..I was edited your comment instead of my question. Just confuse..But any way ..thanks for your comment..My final output should be like this [1,1,1,1] by count not array ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**PHP** use [array_fill](https://www.php.net/array_fill).

```
$value = 1;
$count = 10;
$myArray = array_fill(0,$count,$value);
```

[**DEMO.**](http://codepad.org/swsPkqUX)

**Edited**: After update in question: You can use implode to achieve your expected output,

```
echo $string = "[".implode(",",$myArray)."]";
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.org/IrGuxHAA).**

Comment: Thanks for your help..But My output should be like this [1,1,1,1,1,1,1]. Not an array ..

Comment: Thanks Rikesh..This what I want ..And one doubt .Can we assign php variable to javascript variable ..? like this
$string = "[".implode(",",$myArray)."]";
 <script>
site.Category.panel_counts = <php echo $string ?>;
<script>

Comment: Yes you can definitely. Have a go. If you face any problem in that ask another question with your tried efforts.

Answer (score 4):

**PHP**

Use [`array_fill()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php):

```
$split_one = array_fill( 0, $total, 1);
```

> array_fill — Fill an array with values

**Edit**

For the serialized output, you can then use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode):

```
$string = json_encode( $split_one );
```

---

**JavaScript**

In JavaScript, there is no such convenient functions, so you'll have to manually fill your array:

```
var split_one = [], total = 7;
for( var i=total; i--; ) {
  split_one.push( 1 );
}
```

**Edit**

for the serialized output, you can then use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
var string = JSON.stringify( split_one );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help..But My output should be like this [1,1,1,1,1,1,1]. Not an array ..

Comment: @Elavarasan To have a string like this I suggest (in contrast to accepted answer) to use `json_encode()` in PHP or `JSON.stringify()` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

**PHP:**

```
$split_one = array_fill(0, $total, 1);
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var split_one = Array.apply(this, new Array(total)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help..But My output should be like this [1,1,1,1,1,1,1]. Not an array ..

Answer (score 1):

In JS:

```
var arr = [];
for (var i=0;i<total;i++) {
    arr[i] = 1;
}
```

where `total` is the amount of `1`s you want to add. If you want to output this as a string instead of as an array, you can just run `JSON.stringify(arr)` afterwards to convert this array to a string.

In PHP:

```
$arr = array();
for ($i=0;$i<$total;$i++) {
    $arr[$i] = 1;
}
```

where `$total` is the amount of `1`s you want to add. If you want to output this as a string instead of as an array, you can just run `json_encode($arr);` afterwards to convert this array to a string.

Comment: Thanks for your help..But My output should be like this [1,1,1,1,1,1,1]. Not an array ..

Comment: @Elavarasan what do you mean? Does it have to be a string then? That is what the JSON.stringify and json_encode functions do for JS and PHP respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var arr = new Array();
 count=7;
    for (i=0; i<count; i++) {
       arr[i]=1 
    }
    alert(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript this is:

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0 ;i<total;i++){
   arr.push(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in javascript you can easily do this:

```
var myarray = [];
var total = 7;
var sameNumber = 1;
for(var i=0;i<total;i++) myarray.push(sameNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP:

```
function generator($total, $num)
{
    $split =  [];
    for ($i=0; $i < $total; $i++) { 
            $split[$i] = $num;
    }
    var_dump($split);
}
generator(7,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The array_fill() function fills an array with values.
[image: See this]

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_fill.asp

Answer (score 0):

A different js method:

```
var total=7;

var split_one = Array(total+1).join(" ").split("").map(function(){return 1;});
```